# Insert pdf file into SQL Server linked database

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am new to Access programming and trying to insert `.pdf` and Word documents into SQL Server linked database and having issues. I need some hints to start on this. Could some help.

```
Dim f As Object
Dim sFile As String
Dim fld_path As String
Dim fld_file As String

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim Sql As String
Dim Code As String


 FileToBlob = "C:\temp\1.pdf"

Sql = "INSERT INTO dbo_Doc (Doc) VALUES (FileToBlob)"

DoCmd.RunSQL Sql
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? googeling for the exact T-SQL sintax will yeald tons of answars...

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you trying to insert the file name (`C:\temp\1.pdf`) into the database, or the actual file contents? Your title makes it seem like the former, but your actual code seems like you're trying to do the latter.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am trying to insert the file as oledb object into the database. I can do this thru GUI but I am attempting programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to retrieve byte data for a specified file:

```
' fPath is the path to the file
Function FileToBlob(fPath As String) As Variant
    Dim fileNum As Long
    Dim b() As Byte

    fileNum = FreeFile
    Open fPath For Binary As fileNum
        ReDim b(LOF(fileNum))
        Get fileNum, , b()
    Close fileNum

    FileToBlob = b
End Function
```